# Did the writer of Sword Art Online do a research on guns when writing Gun Gale Online?

Tags: sword-art-online, gun-gale-online

In a number of *Sword Art Offline 2* episodes in Yui's trivia corner, she explains some of the guns seen during the series talking about their real-life counterparts.

Did the writer of *Sword Art Online* do a research on guns when writing *Gun Gale Online*? Did this trivia come after the light novels and used only to give something for Yui to talk about in *Sword Art Offline*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The details of the guns in the game were actually quite basic. Here are three spots in novel #5 that mention specs on real guns used in the game:

- Before the title page- Here, it says facts about Sinon's Hecate II, things like the length of the gun and the size ammo it uses. Also the fact that, in real life, the gun has been banned from being used on human targets.
- Page 137- Kirito asks why the assault rifle fires smaller rounds than a sub-machine gun and Sinon explains that it's for higher speed and accuracy, a trait that has been used since the M16.
- Page 140- Sinon recommends the Five-Seven to Kirito for a sidearm to use with his lightsword. She explains that it uses small bullets shaped like rifle rounds. This gives it an advantage of accuracy and penetration.

The bit in *Sword Art Offline* wasn't included in the light novels, but the trivia on each of the guns is indeed there.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the writer researched about guns.

In the first *Sword Art Online*, he did not research swords at all and it was all about swords.

Asuna has a Rapier. However, a Rapier is a blunt edge sword used exclusively for piercing. It is also useless outside 1-on-1 dueling.

Kirito also dual-wields using two long swords (one is a rapier and one is a sabre if I am not mistaken). Due to the size, dual-sword wielding is only possible either with a long sword and a short sword, or two medium-size swords. 
If both are long swords, they are too big to actually wield. Also, the wielder should have really strong hand muscles or be ambidextrous. But usually, a sword's movement is a circular arch. The bigger the sword, the wider the circle. If they have two big swords, either the two paths intersect or hit the ground and either case is very dangerous. Moreover, it is technically difficult there are few records of it actually being used and no records of being used in battle.

Comment: I'm not sure on the reasoning of him being unable to dual wield two swords other than the ones you suggest.
Is it a balancing issue? i'm sure in the game he was a part of, balance wasn't really an issue, so doing so would be alright, based on that.

other than that I don't know why that'd be out of the question, could you give me a little explanation as to why please?

Comment: not a balancing issue. It is a size issue. If both are long swords they are too big to actually wield. let's forget the fact that you should have really strong hand muscles. Or that you should be ambidextrous. But usually a sword's movement is a circular arch. The bigger the sword the wider the circle. If you have two big sword either the two paths intersect or hit the ground. Each are very dangerous.